# What is the best way to display a selected item in a scrolled side panel?

Tags: sidemenu, user-behaviour

**Scenario:**
I am looking for a banana in a super market website. But when I enter the website there is a side panel with different categories to be clicked.
[image]

Let say that "fruits" are the last category, so I would have to scroll down until I find it.
[image]

After I select this category, the page refreshes and it shows all fruits available.

**Question:**
The category select should be visible.

But
Should it be sticky to the top of the list
Or should it be centralised?

Is there a difference?
Any examples?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The best way to keep the user's attention and not make them think is not to refresh the page. It's better to let the users see the banana/orange/lemon in the sidebar right after they click on the "fruits" category.

If for some reason this is not possible, then you should look at the number of items in this category. If you have a lot of them, then for convenience it is worth fixing them at the top (so that the user feels their number). If there are only a couple of sections within a category, then I would open this category in the same place where you clicked on the opening.

How amazon solves this
[image: How Amazon solves this]

[image]

Comment: Nice. 

Thanks tho

Answer (score 2):

Reordering the menu is not advisable. Our brain and eyes are optimized to know where to look or scroll to based on what we remember but have more difficulty to notice or grasp a change. If the reason for the reorder is to show what the current category and page are, there are better ways.

A few things that can make live easier for your users:

- Add a search field for products and/or a filter for categories to the menu
- Keep the order/position of items and categories in the menu consistent
- Add breadcrumbs to give users direction of where they are

A few things to consider in general

- Add a global search/filter to the site
- Give the menu a second thought (is there a more efficient IA/navigation possible?)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be similar problem I answered in another question asked.

My suggestion is make baskets (groups).
Each group can have an icon representation on top for eg fruits and vegetables can be grouped together and have one icon or can be under a bigger umbrella of grocery
and the layout can change to like below pic
[image]

This way there is no infinite vertical scroll. the menu tab thats active will show covering the other not used one